# Spring MVC can't load CSS, getting error 405

Tags: css, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm building a Spring Boot MVC app using Thymeleaf and I'm having problems with loading static content, such as CSS, into the page.

Whenever I try to load a css file in the template, the request fails with error code `405 Request method 'GET' not supported`.
I've tried multiple different ways to reference the css file, such as

```html
<link href="/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../static/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/static/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link th:href="@{/static/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

basically all the possible combinations of all the previous, still getting the same error.

My file structure looks like this:

```
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── cz
        │       └── company
        │           └── nps
        │               ├── NpsApplication.java
        │               ├── WebConfig.java
        │               └── controller
        │                   └── SurveyController.java
        └── resources
            ├── application.properties
            ├── messages.properties
            ├── messages_CZ.properties
            ├── messages_EN.properties
            ├── static
            │   ├── css
            │   │   └── style.css
            │   ├── img
            │   │   └── favicon.ico
            │   └── js
            └── templates
                ├── footer.html
                ├── header.html
                └── survey.html
```

WebCofig.java:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver()
    {
        final SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("cs", "CZ"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? According to all the materials I've found, this should work without any problems.

**Edit 1:**
build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'cz.company'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.7'
    implementation 'dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1'

    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2'
    implementation 'javax.jws:javax.jws-api:1.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there was a really stupid mistake in the controller.

The original controller class looked like this:

```java
@Controller
public class SurveyController {

    @GetMapping("/nps")
    public String getSurvey() {
        return "survey";
    }

    // TODO
    @PostMapping
    public String postSurvey() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Notice that I've forgotten to add a name to the `@PostMapping` annotation. This seems to cause the issue. When I changed it to `@PostMapping("/nps")`, everything started working fine.

Just in case it helps anyone, I use `<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` to reference the stylesheet.

Comment: Out of curiosity, didn't you need to add either the config in my answer with annotations or Vinod's xml? Glad you got it sorted out though, and it's """"interesting"""" to say the least that accessing the resources can fail because of something like this...

Comment: I've just tested it without the config and it seems to work either way. I believe the `/resources/static` directory is set as the as a resource location implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/static/css/style.css}" />
```

**Update 1:-** Did you have Servlet Mapping for js and CSS in your web.xml?
Check these lines. If it's not present add it and kindly check it again.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately. Request to `http://localhost:8080/static/css/style.css` fails with error code 405 and this is logged in console: `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]`

Comment: @Update 1: I don't have any web.xml file present. Is it necessary? I've found multiple project structures and decided to roll with my current one, which does not contain any XML configuration and web-inf folders.

Comment: @fugasjunior it is not since you are using annotations for your config

Comment: post your pom.xml file

Comment: My project is based on gradle, so I've added `build.gradle` file to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using annotations, add this to your WebConfig class:

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

This should create the mappings your application needs to obtain the resource files (change the resource locations as it suits your needs).

Comment: No luck, still getting the same behaviour. Even tried adding `**` to all the paths, still nothing.